# JavaScript Resize Fun

Tags: javascript, css

Trying to write a function to calculate proper margins.

```
    window.addEventListener('resize', function () {
    order = document.getElementById('image-1').width;

    document.getElementById("destop_thumb").style.marginLeft =   `calc(( (( 100vw / 3 ) - (${order}px) ) / 2) - 30px ) `  ;
    document.getElementsByClassName("product-shop-wrapper")[0].style.marginLeft =   `calc((((33.3333vw - 369px) / 2) * -1 ) + 30px)`    ;


    });
```

I'm at battle with my CSS stylesheet and this JavaScript function. I need this line to take precedence on my webpage:

```
 document.getElementById("destop_thumb").style.marginLeft =   `calc(( (( 100vw / 3 ) - (${order}px) ) / 2) - 30px ) `  ;
```

I figure if I set it to !important it will work, but,

```
 document.getElementById("destop_thumb").style.marginLeft =   `calc(( (( 100vw / 3 ) - (${order}px) ) / 2) - 30px )  !important`  ;
```

doesn't do the trick.

Comment: I dont understand. JavaScript styling should always take precedence on css styles.

Comment: Did you check your browser inspector to see which styles are taking precedence over these inline styles?